# If TDD is for units, how can a test accidentally pass first (as a mistake)?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd

I have read a study about TDD and one of the common issues (survey between developers) stated that they are not really letting the test fail first. The authors then state:

> If a new test does not fail, programmers receive an indication that
>   the production code was not working as they thought it was and a code
>   revision might be necessary. Another problem that might occur is that
>   programmers cannot be sure about what made the test pass; nothing
>   ensures the new code was actually responsible for it. The test
>   implementation might have been wrong since the beginning.

I wonder, how can a TDD test ever pass first **(because of the production code, like they mention)**, if it on a unit level? I mean, if all is mocked (stubbed..), it should be always isolated and thus never cannot really pass first.

Comment: `assert expectedValue == expectedValue` oops

Comment: @Ryan You are right, I did not specify that in the question - I would be curious about their note about a production code. I believe that a test should be isolated from the production code.

Comment: “Production code” there seems to refer to the code before the changes the test was written for were made. (Of course, not all automated tests are unit tests. I’m personally against mocking pretty much anything.)

Comment: If you start with test like `Should not save item when value is invalid` - test will pass with empty function in production code

Comment: In most of the cases _If a new test does not fail_ - mean that feature is already implemented, to be sure developer can write another test which will approach to same feature with different values for example

Comment: @Fabio That is what I have troubles to understand. Unless the test is integrating something, how could a blank method pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you have two classes `Calculator` and `Formatter`.

`Calculator` calculates some value based on input and `Formatter` converts the value to string for displaying.

You already have some tests in your `FormatterTest`:

- `test_value_is_formatted_as_number`
- `test_empty_is_formatted_as_NA`

Now you implement new feature `Show zero values as N/A`.

Following TDD you will add a test to `Formatter` `test_zero_is_formatted_as_NA` that checks this first and you expect it to fail:

```py
def test_zero_is_formatted_as_NA(self):
    assert formatter.format(0) == 'N/A'
```

But it happens that it passes and the reason is `Formatter` already does this but `Calculator` returns floating zero which has limited precision.

```py
def format(value):
    if value == 0 or value is None:
        return 'N/A'
    return format_as_string(value)
```

So the test passes but if you write another test it would fail:

```py
def test_very_small_number_is_treated_as_zero_and_formatted_as_NA(self):
    assert formatter.format(0.00000001) == 'N/A'
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, situations that you describe easily happen when something is already implemented but another part of the system (using this implemented part) is somehow limiting it, for example by stronger preconditions. Then if you do not know well the code, you might encounter such a surprise.

Consider this example:

```
public string ShowScoreEvaluation(byte points)
{
    switch(points)
     case 3:
        return "You are good!";
     case 2:
        return "Not bad!";
     case 1:
        return "Quite bad";
     case 0:
        return "You suck!"

}

//caller code
if (Points>0)
  ShowScoreEvaluation(points)
```

In the code above, the calling code does not expect to call the method when Points=0. Maybe during the implementation of that method, the programmer just put something there (as a joke or a placeholder) even for the case when points=0.

And now imagine, that you joins the project and get a new request "When player has 0 points, show an encouraging message blabla". 
You write a unit test with Points=0 and expecting a string with length>0...and it did not fail, although you would expect it.